# How to subset String object in R

Tags: r, string, substring, bioconductor

I have an `AAString ()` object like below, how can I subset for multiple positions?

```
df <- AAString("HAKTKIDLTBI")
df

11-letter AAString object
seq: HAKTKIDLTBI
```

I want to subset for :

```
substring(df,c(1,3,4,10))
```

Output:

```
seq: HKTB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard indices

```r
df <- AAString("HAKTKIDLTBI")
df[c(1,3,4,10)]
##  4-letter AAString object
##  seq: HKTB
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the approach applies to `AAString` object, but you can have a try

```
> s <- "HAKTKIDLTBI"

> idx <- c(1, 3, 4, 10)

> paste0(substring(s, idx, idx), collapse = "")
[1] "HKTB"
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, unfortunately, it is not working for AAString.